# How to Sum a value and also show the original value

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I want to pull data from a table where i sum column3 as Total and then i want to show the orignal value of column3 as well for all the rows that have column1 = 1

Example

```
 colum1 column2 column3
  1         2456      20.00
  2         2456      -5.00
  1         2457      30.00
  2         2457      -5.00
```

I did a

```
select a.column1,a.column2, sum(a.column3), b.column3 as total 
from table A 
inner join table B on a.column2 = b.column2 
group by a.column1
```

but it wont all alow to put b.column3 as part of my select.

```
 colum1 column2      column3     total
  1         2456      20.00      15.00
  1         2457      30.00      25.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Aggregate Function`

```
SELECT column1,column2, MAX(column3), SUM(column3) AS Total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY column1,column2
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dd26/1)**

Comment: Than you. if  i wanted a column4 and a column5 but not have them part of the group by would i use a join. they are in the same table

Comment: Why did you change sample data? That won't work for [the given data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4f64c3e3d4ace82f14154d526190675) by the OP.

Comment: Yes agreed dropping column1 completely and using the max function does what i need

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column2) as id,
       column2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN column1 = 1 THEN column3 END) as column3,
       SUM(column3) AS Total
FROM t
GROUP BY column2
```

I don't know how the first column in the result set is calculated.  I'm assuming it is essentially a row number.